# imagecolorsforindex(): Color index 244 out of range when converting animated gif to jpg

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel and the [SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage) class to convert images to thumbnails.

this is the code that converts the images and produces the error:

```
    $img = new SimpleImage(public_path() . '/img/temp/' . $rnd . '.' . $ext);
    $img->fit_to_width(125)->save(public_path().'/img/thumbs/'.$rnd.'.jpg');
    unlink(public_path().'/img/temp/'.$rnd.'.'.$ext);
```

the variables $rnd and $ext are assigned before this code. Also, not all gifs produce this error, some work, some don't.

I can't figure it out..

Comment: That's a `gd` error. nothing to do, really, with simpleimage.

Comment: @MarcB hmmm thats a shame

Comment: I'd guess it's a bug in gd. each frame of an animated gif can have its own separate pallette, and gd may be "optimizing" by assuming that the palette from one frame applies to all frames. just a guess, though...